# PHP_AUTH_USER only known in certain frames

Tags: php, authentication

Getting very confused by PHP_AUTH_USER. Within my web pages I have .htaccess files in every directory, controlling who can (and cant) see certain folders. In order to further customise the pages I was hoping to use PHP_AUTH_USER within the PHP code, i.e. tailor page contents based on the user.

This only seems to work partially. The code snippets below hopefully demonstrate my problems.

The main index.php creates a framed page with a menu structure in the top left hand corners, some irrelvant stuff in top right and then the tailor made contents in bottom frame. In top left the user is correctly shown, but in the bottom frame PHP_AUTH_USER doesnt seem to be set anymore (it returns empty and when printing all $HTTP_SERVER_VARS its not listed).

Script.php is in a different path, but they all have .htaccess files in them and all other contents is displayed correctly. Why does it not know about PHP_AUTH_USER there?

Running version php version 5.2.12 on chrome.

index.php

```
 <FRAMESET ROWS="35%, *">
 <FRAMESET COLS="25%, *">
 <FRAME SRC="Menu.php">
 <FRAME SRC="Something.php">
 </FRAMESET>
     <FRAME SRC="../OtherPath/Script.php?large=1" name="outputlisting">
   </FRAMESET>
</FRAMESET>
```

Menu.php

```
<ul>
<li>Reporting
<ul>
<li>Link1 <a href="../OtherPath/Script.php" target="outputlisting">All</a>, <a href="../OtherPath/Script.php?large=1"  target="outputlisting">Big</a>
</ul>
<?php
echo 'IP Address: ' . $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] . '<br />';
echo 'User: ' . $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'];
?>
```

Script.php

```
<?php 
echo 'User: ' . $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'];
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I just did a test using the code you provided and could not reproduce. The username correctly showed up on both pages-- even when I removed the .htaccess from one of the directories.

What version of Apache are you running? How is PHP configured? Which MPM worker is being utilized?